# Is nesting drawer navigation inside of tab navigation possible?

Tags: node.js, nested, expo, react-navigation-bottom-tab

These are the imports I have on my 'Navigation.js'.

`import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";`
`import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";`

I have started to search through the documents and came across the **Nesting Navigators** portion. I was wondering if there is any way to nest a drawer navigator into the *Tab.Navigator* or into the actual 'screenname.js'; I have had trouble finding examples of this as my navigator is a tab and not a stack. I'll continue working and reading but I'm thankful for any insight.

```
export default function RootNavigation() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator 
        initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
              let iconName;
  
              if (route.name === 'Home') {
                iconName = focused
                  ? 'funnel-outline'
                  : 'funnel';
              } else if (route.name === 'ASYNCH') {
                iconName = focused ? 'scan' : 'scan-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'Config') {
                iconName = focused ? 'earth-outline' : 'earth';
              } else if (route.name === 'Search') {
                iconName = focused ? 'terminal' : 'terminal-outline';
              } else if (route.name === 'status') {
                iconName = focused ? 'code-slash' : 'code-slash-outline';
              }

              return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
            },
              tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000000',
              tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#000000',
              headerShown: false,
          })}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen name="ASYNCH" component={sc2} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Config" component={sc3} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search} />
          <Tab.Screen name="status" component={statusbar} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```